# Maclaurin Expansion of $\ln(1+4x^2+4x)$ in terms of $\sum a_k x^k$

Tags: taylor-expansion

Maclaurin Expansion of $\ln(1+4x^2+4x)$ in terms of $\sum a_k x^k$

The question has written to $x^2$ term before the $x$ - does that have anything to do with how to solve the problem? Am I meant to use the known expansion of $\ln(1+x)$?

Comment: $$\ln(1+4x^2+4x) = \ln(1+2x)^2 = 2\ln (1+2x)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your work using logarithm's properties:
$$1 + 4x^2 + 4x = (1 + 2x)^2 \implies \ln(1 + 4x^2 + 4x) = \ln\left((1 + 2x)^2\right) = 2\ln(1 + 2x)$$

Since as $x \to 0$, $2x \to 0$, you can directly apply MacLaurin expansion
$$\ln(1 + t) = t - \frac{t^2}2 + \frac{t^3}3 - \frac{t^4}4 + \cdots$$
yielding
$$\begin{align}
2\ln(1 + 2x) &= 2\left(2x - \frac{4x^2}2 + \frac{8x^3}3 - \frac{16x^4}4 + \cdots\right) = \\
&=4x - 4x^2 + \frac{16x^3}{3} - 8x^4 + \cdots
\end{align}$$

It's not difficult to express this sum as a closed form.